# Android studio test package won't autocomplete

Tags: android, testing, robolectric

I'm using android studio and have been able to properly [import Robolectric](http://www.element84.com/easy-testing-with-android-studio.html).

When writing code in the test class it responds as though I'm simply using a textEditor.
To give an example of my problem: When I create a POJO I am able to give the constructor a the wrong arguments and the IDE doesn't respond at all.

And i do have the correct POJO import.

Comment: What version of Android Studio is this?

Comment: built on june 20 2013. AI 130.71    and JRE 1.6.0_45

Comment: That version is ancient. Upgrade.

Comment: Now it autocompletes but doesn't auto correct. I can write junk.something(); and it won't put a red line even if there's no junk object.

Answer (score 0):

Powersave mode!

Put it off and your ide will work as usually ;)